# Dynamically add a key:value to object only if condition is true

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I want to dynamically add a key and value. If data attribute type email is present I want to add email true if it is false I dont want email to be added to the object.

**Current result is**

```
fname: {
   presence: true,
   email: false
},
femail: {
   presence: true,
   email: true
}
```

**Expected Results**

```
fname: {
   presence: true,
},
femail: {
   presence: true,
   email: true
}
```

**code**

```
constraints[name] = {
    presence: true,
    email: _this.getAttribute("type") === "email" ? true : false
};
```

Comment: Break the ternary out of the code, and do an actual if check that only sets it to true if it exists.

Comment: `if(whatever.email) objectToModify.email = true`

Comment: It looks like you are using a validation package - and that this is all specific to that.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context - this is all I can really say about that.

```
// "I have an object that I want to dynamically add a key and value..."   
var exampleObject = {};

// "If data attribute type email is present..."
if (emailDataAttribute) {
  exampleObject.email = true; // "I want to add email true..."
}
// "if it is false I dont want email to be added to the object."
```